# Why syntax error is coming in my angularjs project

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

In my angularJS project I'm getting below error. Can you please help me?

***Error***

angular.min.js:117Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.6/$parse/syntax?p0=Shoping&p1=is%20an%20unexpected%20token&p2=8&p3=Online%20Shoping%20-%20login&p4=Shoping%20-%20login
    at Error (native)
    at localhost:8082/onlineshopping/angular.min.js:6:412
    at Object.s.throwError (localhost:8082/onlineshopping/angular.min.js:228:143)
    at Object.s.ast (localhost:8082/onlineshopping/angular.min.js:220:47)
    at Object.td.compile (localhost:8082/onlineshopping/angular.min.js:229:420)
    at kc.parse (localhost:8082/onlineshopping/angular.min.js:258:213)
    at g (localhost:8082/onlineshopping/angular.min.js:125:278)
    at k (localhost:8082/onlineshopping/angular.min.js:105:129)
    at $ (localhost:8082/onlineshopping/angular.min.js:77:397)
    at $b (localhost:8082/onlineshopping/angular.min.js:61:398)

> My HTML Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Online Shopping - Login Page</title>
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href=".\WEB-INF\lib\css\Styles.css"/> -->
</head>
<body ng-app>
    <div style="text-align:center">
        <h1>{{Online Shoping - login}}</h1>
        <form action="login_submit" name="login" method="get">
            Email Address: <input type="email" placeholder="username@mail.com" required/><br><br>
            Password: <input type="password" placeholder="password" required/><br><br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `Online Shoping` isn't a valid variable name, Angular will try to interpret that as two variables `Online` and `Shopping` one after the other which isnt valid.

Comment: I am new to AngularJS. I didn't check in detail. Now I got. Thanks Patrick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to update the `<h1></h1>` tage like

```
 <h1>Online Shoping - {{login}}</h1>
```

or you can also use `<h1></h1>` like

```
{{'Online Shopping - '+ login}}
```

for more details click fiddler [link here](https://jsfiddle.net/manishki/4cd004p4/)

Comment: Got it. Thanks Manish. Now it is working fine :)
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong `{{Online Shoping - login}}` because `Online Shoping` is not a value nor valid syntax. You can use a string and concatenate the value:

```
{{'Online Shopping - '+ login}}
```

Or simply interpolate where needed only:

```
<h1>Online Shopping - {{login}}</h1>
```